# How to disable the home key

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I'd like to lock the screen. I want to disable the home key and only use the back key. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: see here, the fast answer it seems you need to implement a home screen replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953689/how-to-lock-android-buttons-phone-from-code-screen-lock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button/3955217#3955217 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically http://www.toddlerlock.com/3.html

Comment: Hi.. Have you got the solution. i'm also trying to disable Home key for my lock screen app, but its not working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use this method to disable the Home key in android

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Comment: Does this work with a fullscreen SurfaceView and MediaPlayer? Seems like it does not. Oh I got it: in this case TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG works.

Comment: The user will still be able to slide down the Notification Bar... and once the bar is down they can click home and it will work.

Comment: Have you tried it? I dont think so that the notification bar would work.

Comment: The notification bar still shows up and after bringing the notification bar down, pressing the home key goes back to the home screen. Any work arounds? Theme.Black.NoTitleBar and requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) doesn't work.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this issue: my fullscreen activity still exits when pressing the home button, even if I call setType with keyguard. Should I use an API level higher than Android 2.3?

Comment: I tried TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG with SurfaceView  and it works greatly

Comment: Back key is blocked by this but not the home key.

Comment: its throws exception of illegalstate exception

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on modern Android versions. It throws an exception that one can't change the type of the window after it had been added.

Answer (score 23):

I found a way to tackle the HOME key.
For your application set the manifest as

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
```

Now your application is an alternate Launcher application.

Use the adb, and disable the launcher application using package manager

```
pm disable com.android.launcher2
```

Now the Home key press will always stay in the same screen.

Comment: pm disable com.android.launcher2 should be pm disable com.android.launcher

Comment: @ kakopappa the package launcher is no longer used. The package is launcher2. Check the code in Git

Comment: I was try like this but i did't get exactly how to do this? will you please give me source code for more detail. thanks.

Comment: Hi I just want to disable the home key and not the back key. how this can be acheived?

Comment: I have added above attributes to my activity in manifest file but still the home button takes my to launcher home screen even though I have set my app as default home screen. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks man saved my day how to uninstall the app :) just disable these filters:
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

Answer (score 13):

This solution works up to 3.x only.

Okay, this was supposed to be a hard question. But here is a way to crack it.

Override the below method in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

And now handle the key event like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
     Log.i("Home Button","Clicked");
    }
   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
   {
        finish();
   }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: In the ideal sense.. the KEYCODE_HOME will NEVER be returned to any app.

Comment: My app crashes with this: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.

Comment: ...I moved the setType() call from onAttached to onCreate -- now no crash, but the home button isn't disabled.

Comment: Even if the api level is set to under ICS?

Answer (score 9):

Add this code to your `MainActivity` class:

```
Timer timer;
MyTimerTask myTimerTask;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    if (timer == null) {
        myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 100, 100);
    }

    super.onPause();
}

private void bringApplicationToFront()
{
    KeyguardManager myKeyManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if( myKeyManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
        return;

    Log.d("TAG", "====Bringging Application to Front====");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    try
    {
        pendingIntent.send();
    }
    catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    // do not call super onBackPressed.
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bringApplicationToFront();
    }
}
```

It's not a locking for 'home' button, but user can't switch to another app for a long time (more than 100 milliseconds), maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Avoid blinking change this line `timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 100, 100);` to `timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1, 100);`

Answer (score 1):

To disable home button, try this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Problem with notification bar pulled down can be solved by hiding notification bar like here:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxxx);
    getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ....
}
```

or set fullscreen theme for your Activity or Application in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```