# How to make an App Locker for Android

Tags: android

I want to make an App Locker app for Android. The app should run on various devices. It seems that Android does not allow the developer to do such low level work.

Please guide me how can a developer make such an application.

Comment: You're right, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852713) answer will help You. It used a background service to check which application is in foreground and then check whether I need to lock the application or not.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can develope a new home screen replacement app, that allows the user to run only some apps, and not all the apps installed on the system.
Some useful hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4538431/584134

But it's only a facade, it's not reliable and the user must launch and use your application instead of the default android home screen.

Or you can use another app, [Android Parental Control](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vlobe.smartappcloud.android.parentalcontrol)