# Blocking android apps programmatically

Tags: android, password-protection

I tried to develop such an app, in the sense I want to lock all the applications in my device with a password whatever I want. But I didn't find any piece of code for the solution. So I developed one by myself and unfortunately it didn't succeed. I found many solutions for locking android devices but, didn't find one for locking an app. Will be glad if you suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you want to lock an application at the time of accessing. If yes then i will help you bcz i have developed an application in which user will able to lock (any or all) installed application in the device.

Comment: @AmitGupta I am also facing same problem .I want to lock an application at the time of accessing..Can help me :)

Comment: Hi Amit.. I do want the same. Want to lock at the time of accessing the app. :)

Comment: @AmitGupta   i have tried ur code it looks fine but whenever i m trying to open any app then my app using service is not detecting app package name of that app

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I used a background service to check which application is in the foreground (which means that application is being used by the user). Then I check to see whether I need to lock the application or not.

To find the list of all installed applications (excluding system applications):

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> appList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo;
    // skip system apps if they shall not be included
    if ((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    appList.add(p.packageName);
}
```

To find the current foreground application:

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
```

Here the class-name provides the package name of the application. I suggest that you use the package name to identify any application so we know that the package name is always unique.

**Now, the functionality to lock the application:**

To find which application is running in the foreground and want to lock it, we just have to start another activity which has an EditText for password and OK and Cancel button.

```
Intent lockIntent = new Intent(mContext, LockScreen.class);
lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(lockIntent);
```

On click of OK, if the password is correct then simply **finish** the LockScreen activity. If the password is incorrect then simply use the code below, which closes the application and shows the home screen of the device:

```
Intent startHomescreen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startHomescreen.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startHomescreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(startHomescreen);
```

The same code is also used on the cancel button.

Comment: **@Shakeeb Shaheen** and **thampi joseph** if you have any query related to this post feel free to ask...

Comment: Hey wait.. I want to block the system app as well as the app running in backround also. Can you help me in that too?? :)

Comment: In the sense, applications like watsapp and Google map are always running in background. I want to block that too :)

Comment: yes you can do this just remove this code
if((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
    {
    continue;
    }
and u will get a list of all installed application either it is system app or third party application.

Comment: It helped me alot but need one more help how to start the same application if password is true

Comment: @AmitGupta you are awesome and your answer also. thnx

Comment: This was a clever way to get the thing done. I was earlier trying to kill the process related to package name, but it got restarted every time. Kudos!

Comment: It works. But I have a problem. If user enters correct password, the locked app is on foreground again, and the service locks the app again. How to allow locked app on foreground if user enters correct password?

Comment: I have a question: In the first code snippet; where does the object "apps" come from? 
You call apps.add(p.packageName); but that name isn't used at all up until that point.

Comment: @Bhavika  did u find solution for your query how to start the same application if password is true

Comment: @AmitGupta  why i need service for that ? just to find that which app is going to be opened i m not getting service will do  which type of work ?

Comment: @MD  CAN u tell me when i m trying to launch any app from home screen then my app should detect those app package name right now its only detecting my own app package name

Comment: Intent lockIntent = new Intent(mContext, LockScreen.class);
lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(lockIntent);  this code is not opening new activity if package name matches and even not coming inside if conditioon while package name is correct

Comment: @AmitGupta can u pls help me i have started service but when i close my app and trying to access any other app my service is not showing any logcat about current accessed app package name

Comment: @nida yes i used background service to check Which app is in foreground and if we need to apply lock on that app that code also written in that service

Comment: @Erum Hannan  yes we need to apply lock code in this service

Comment: How can i lock the app after the application is closed ( or exit ) and for a specific time. 
means if i use an application for 10 mins i want to block that application for 20 mins after exit.

Comment: `mActivityManager.getRunningTasks` is deprecated as of Lollipop. From the official documentation: _This method was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak personal information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks (though see getAppTasks() for the correct supported way to retrieve that information), and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive._

Comment: @GauravManral, did you find how to lock app for specific time?

Comment: I using this on  App Laucher it always shows AppLaucher name on top whenever i am opening a new app its shows only applauncher package how can i resolve this @AmitGupta

Comment: Hi sunil i am not getting your point clearly please attach any screen shot or explain in detail what problem you are facing

Comment: @ Phuc Tran:- need help in (It works. But I have a problem. If user enters correct password, the locked app is on foreground again, and the service locks the app again. How to allow locked app on foreground if user enters correct password?). please share how to resolve that issue?

Comment: So many thanks to you @AmitGupta, you save my life, i have been research for 3 days about this. Thanks.

Comment: @AmitGupta Your code works, but I have simple problem, I am making app locker, then how can I get notify when other app lunch and get the package name, Tried with background service but it just execute once and print my app's package name, any idea? help would be highly appreciate.

Comment: @Smit.Satodia I used background servce too for my application but you also need to use timer inside the background service which will execute in every 2 seconds and you will check that which app is in forground, i also used the same concept

Comment: @AmitGupta Android 6.0.1. The code for getting foreground app shows the activity name including package name of the app from which it is called from (when that app is in foreground) but when any other app is opened, it shows the name of the launcher. So what could be the possible issue in this case. I understand that you've worked on it a long time ago. PS. Is there a better alternative or a solution to this. Cheers

Comment: @7geeky Sorry, i have worked on this long time ago and didn't try it for new version, so i can not give a good solution for this problem

Comment: @AmitGupta No worries, your answer lead me to a solution (posted below now). and thanks

Comment: Hi, I successfully the open lock activity when other application open which I need to ask password but when user enters correct password its show my app instead of the app for which I opened the activity. How to open lock screen and close it without open my app in background. Please help I am stuck here.

Comment: @RahulVats You have the package name of the activity you have locked, why won't you launch the same app using the package name when user enters the correct password. hope it works

Comment: @AmitGupta Hi Let me check will let you know if it works.

Comment: @PhucTran have you found any solution , how to launch the same app after successful password . because its open my lock app

Comment: Are you checking foreground app in service continuously? i.e after every second??

Comment: Yes I was checking foreground app in service continuously.

Comment: something wrong with code: appList.add(p.packageName); ?

Comment: Not Sure!, How you were able to get the Foreground running app used by the user, when the method you used will return only the list of tasks of your calling application

Comment: can you build an example application as a public repository so that it will be helpful

Comment: how i know time of the launch locked app? may bee have some listener laucnhed app?

Answer (score 15):

Looks like this is still a mystery as suggested by above mentioned comments.So I'm putting the code that helped me to solve this problem.

**getForegroundApp**

```
public String getForegroundApp() {
    String currentApp = "NULL";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }

    return currentApp;
}
```

Call `getForegroundApp()` and it will return a string which contains the name of the currentForegroundApp including the package name e.g. `com.example.app`

Now, to use this code, we need this line of code in `Manifest` file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
```

and take user to `Usage Data access Settings`:

**usageAccessSettingsPage**

```
  public void usageAccessSettingsPage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mContext.getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

or manually by finding in `LockScreen and Security`> `Other security settings`> `Usage access data`.

Now comes the part for blocking the app, this part is covered in Amit's answer very well. However, if someone is looking for a way to restrict user from using an app then a trick is to open home screen when a particular app is launched.

This could be done by calling the following method when the `currentApp` is equal to a blocked app

```
if(<NameOfBlockedApp>.equals currentApp){
     showHomeScreen();
   }
```

**ShowHomeScreen**

```
 public boolean showHomeScreen(){
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(startMain);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I successfully the open lock activity when other application open which I need to ask password but when user enters correct password its show my app instead of the app for which I opened the activity. How to open lock screen and close it without open my app in background. Please help I am stuck here.

Comment: @RahulVats Ask a new question and link here

Comment: @RahulVats  have you found any solution , how to launch the same app after successful password . because its open my lock app .

Comment: on password match use below code   Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name_to_start);
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                    
                    finish();

Comment: Are you checking for the Foreground App in service continuously ? after every second `getForegroundApp();` is called? if YES, is there any way to only call the method when a new app is launched to save battery?

Comment: @Tabish Hi ! Did you get any answer to your question ?

Comment: @BhavitS.Sengar Unfortunately no! I am still going with this solution and checking for recent app in a loop

Comment: @BhavitS.Sengar ^

Comment: @7geeky It's the exact same thing

Comment: @Tabish Why can't we do one thing ! We should register for the broadcasts for phone lock and unlock. When user locks the phone, we should stop the service, so that it doesn't consume the battery, at least when user is not using the phone. And whenever he unlocks the phone, we'll start the service again. Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere, or if it's not feasible.

Comment: @BhavitS.Sengar yes actually i've implemented this also ... when device is in sleep mode I'm killing the service and starting it only if device is awake

Comment: @Tabish Can you please tell me how do you kill and restart the service when a device in sleep mode? I'm new with Android programming and couldn't find any way to do this?