# Screen Crack Application on Android

Tags: android, view, screen, overlay

I am planning to create a screen crack app

I have managed to display a cracked screen over the current screen.

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LNActivity" 
               android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"   />



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>


getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

But it is not displaying above all activities like home,app menu,other apps.

Comment: This question is answered here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: I want to show that crack screen on all screens. When I click back button or home it vanished.I dont want to be like that.

Comment: You cannot have your app displayed over other activities while those other activities are active.  You can create a transparent activity so that when your app is run the user will see what's underneath.  However if a user presses "home" button, your activity will be removed from the screen and the main home screen will be shown.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key) might help you with disabling home key.

Comment: Ya, I want overlay only.I have seen app like "crack your screen" and "better cracked" working as overlay on top of all pages like home, contacts.....