# Disable Home button in Android 4.0 or above

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Is It possible to disable the click of home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button)

I want to disable the home button and set even on the home button to open some app.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Whatever version you may be using but **IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO DISABLE HOME BUTTON PROGRAMATICALLY IN ANDROID.**

Comment: how could you say its not possible on all the versions of android, look this link man-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key

Comment: Don't give me no for an answer because there are many 'lock' apps in the market that provide this functionality.