# How to disable HOME key for Android launcher application

Tags: android

Is it possible to hide/disable Device home key for Screen lock application. I tired to create a sample screen lock application, i did the following testing process,

1. Device screen is off
2. Clicked search button - Lock screen will appear and nothing will happened
3. Clicked Back button - Lock screen will appear and nothing will happened
4. Clicked Menu button - Lock screen will appear and nothing will happened
5. **Clicked Home Button - Lock screen will removed and redirect to device home page.**

In my manifest.xml is,

```
<activity
            android:name=".SampleLock"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" /> -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Guys any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Hardik: Then how the GoLocker and other locker apps are did?

Comment: sorry for fast comment see my answer

Comment: here is your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key

Comment: @Hardik: No probs.. but i already did this too.. it didn't work me. :(

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button

Answer (score 1):

For disabling home button just add this permission in your Manifest.xml:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

For disabling Recent button add this code to your Main activity:

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus) {
        windowCloseHandler.post(windowCloserRunnable);
    }
}
private void toggleRecents() {
    Intent closeRecents = new Intent("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
    closeRecents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    ComponentName recents = new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity");
    closeRecents.setComponent(recents);
    this.startActivity(closeRecents);
}
private Handler windowCloseHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable windowCloserRunnable = new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
    if (cn != null && cn.getClassName().equals("com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity")) {
        toggleRecents();
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your manifest deceleration

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

it must be

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```