# how to prevent use of HOME button in android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, home-button

I am working on an application in which user should be able to use only one application,
he should not be able to switch application using HOME button,
the app. should be closed only when user presses the close button..
I have managed to override return button, don't know how to disable HOME button.

Comment: you can't disable home button. search on stackoverflow you will find many similar posts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key

Comment: for iOS (not sure if its iPad only) you could use Kiosk mode: http://www.ipadenclosures.com/blog/posts/your-ipad-into-a-kiosk

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to disable the Home Button in android When application is in the background because it might some application always disable the home button if it's possible. So this is the reason developer can't disable the home button when app in background. But In the Activity, you can intercept the home button.

In Activity you can disable the Home key in android. It work till Android 3.x only.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TGMCians is right.

Android will not let an activity and its services run completely alone on your device.

Using Override you can capture button clicks (home, back and menu) when your activity is in the foreground. If an activity/service has full control from the background you would not be able to switch for an incoming sms, e-mails, phone calls, etc either.

Personally I think its dangerous to override the home and back button together, if the activity hangs at some point, you can not get out of the app unless you restart the phone.

Personally, I do override the back key for exit, or return to main screen events, but leave the home button alone.

Comment: you can't capture the home key in the usual way like the back button or the menu button. it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using code at all on iOS, ever.

Answer (score 0):

One usage of HOME button is for emergency situation.

Any house, apartment ... they all have an emergency method, like emergency door (exit), glass breaker (axe, bat ...); it saves life.
Similarly, on Android/iOS phone, HOME button saves users' lives (well, kind of). If HOME button is dead, the phone is considered dead as well as required an instant reboot for refresh. The button was designed for such a purpose, so that developers can't messed-up with everything.

Personally, I'm kinda of being thankful for Android/iOS framework team and whoever thought of this situation on HOME button. It saves my development so many times. I suggest you should think and consider the worst case possible if HOME button is not working in your app; for example, app fails to function as normal, HOME is disabled, so how to back to HOME screen, how to switch to other apps?...

The code provided by TGMCians is not working on 4.0+.

In case, you are working on Android framework, such as building ROMs, building frameworks for manufacturers, ... grep the source code with `KEY_HOME` and trace inner-depth to find how it works and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

actually, it is possible to block the home button using the next methods:

1. use of security holes, at least on old android versions. this is done on some locker apps. i think some still work even on newer android versions, but it's a risk and it might be buggy on some devices. i know that "widgetLocker" and "Picture Password Lockscreen" try out those holes. i'm not sure how well they work now with them. best solution of becoming a lockscreen is #2 .
2. make your app a launcher app, which will handle the home button (user must confirm it of course). an example of such an app is "MagicLocker" , and in fact any launcher app...
3. using a rooted device. i have no idea how to do it, but i think it's very possible.
4. not quite a blocking method, but you could have your app full screen and on top (using the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window layout type) , so home button won't be captured, but the user won't see what's going on behind your app. the downside is that any other button won't be captured by your app, since it's not really on the foreground.