# How to disable home button lik in Kids Place application?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to develop a parental control application, so I need to block home button, when user clicks on home button he is redirected to another activity of my application.
I used these two lines in AndroidManifest

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

But, I want to redirect user without giving him a choice between application and launcher.

Any one can help me?

Comment: You miss the fundamentals. Try reading this page: developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I don't think so @Der Golem

Comment: You don think so, but your question **reveals** a deep lack of the very basics of Android programming

Comment: I want to block home button not to start activity when clicking on a simple button, can you help me @Der Golem?

Comment: But this asks how to start another activity: `How to redirect user to another activity` - Anyway, to disable the home button, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7964513/2649012

Comment: It appears to work on 2.2 too

Comment: Thanks @Der Golem, the problem is that I have to work in version higher than 2.3 . this solution is only functional for versions lower than Android 2.3?

Comment: No I m sure, we can't Override Home button in version higher than 2.3

Comment: So... It not considered a good practice to override the home button. But you can always use ActionBarSherrlock, which will allow you to `use setHomeButtonEnabled() and the rest of the ActionBar API from API Level 7 to the latest`

Answer (score 0):

You can use service such as:

```
try {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(thisActivity, Reciver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 2, intent1, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long l = new Date().getTime();
//You can increase/decrease time "1200" in millisecond
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 1200, sender);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Create class `Reciver`:

```
public class Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //call check Running Applications method.
        MainActivity.checkRunningApplications();
    }
}
```

in activity add function `checkRunningApplications()`

```
public static void checkRunningApplications() {
ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) thisActivity.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            String packageName = am1.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

if(packageName!="Your App Package Name"){
       //open Anthor Activity
   }
else{
       //Nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mohammad, But whith your solution I have this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Activity" in checkRunningApplications() method

Comment: static Activity thisActivity = null; and in oncreate
thisActivity  =this;

Comment: it still displays a dialog box that asks to choose between launcher and my application, how to remove this dialog box and redirect user to my application

Comment: ok add this to your code in checkRunningApplications():
   Intent LaunchIntent = thisActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Your App Package Name");
    thisActivity.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    thisActivity.finish();

Comment: The user can set your home screen as the default home screen, such as by pressing HOME and choosing your app as the default. However, you cannot force the user to accept your home screen as the default.