# How can I bring the call screen to front programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony, telephonymanager

I'm working on a home replacement app for people with eyesight problems. I don't want users to leave the call screen during a call by mistake.

I'm trying to bring the screen to front programatically if the user accidentally went back to my launcher during a call, but I haven't been able to figure how to do it. This is what I'm trying right now:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // If call state offhook, go back to current call
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephony.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, null);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
    }
```

How can I bring the call screen to front?

Comment: I may be oversimplifying this, but wouldn't a simple Intent like ACTION_CALL (with no data - should just open the app) or ACTION_CALL_BUTTON do? Maybe even ACTION_DIAL?

Comment: Are you building a system app with system privileges? What Android version(s) are you targeting?

Comment: [have a look on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4538431/3049917)

Comment: I'm support versions from 2.2. I would accept an answer that fits the purpose even if it doesn't support some versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a different approach, hide the menu at the bottom of the screen. In this way the user cannot mistakenly hit any of the buttons during a call. To do this all you need to do is add the following line of code during a call:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

It would therefore look similar to the screen below:

[image]

How does that approach sound? Hope it may help you :)

Comment: Hi Michele, I'm sorry but it's not what I'm looking for. Just curious where should I add that line? it seems to me if I do it before opening the call I'll only hide the menu on my activity.