# How to disable Android home and back button from Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, back-button, delphi-xe7

I'm writing an app for an Android tablet in Delphi XE7. I want to turn off home and back button so no one can leave the application. I have found many answers, but none refers to Delphi.

How can I achieve this in Delphi? What objects should I use? Which units I need to include?

Comment: Please keep it in english as it will be easier for everyone to understand.

Comment: `I want to turn off home...` - Can you even disable the home button on an Android app? I would be very surprised if you could...

Comment: @David If your app is Point of Sale app or something similar, you may want to have it locked in. This is perfectly valid requirement, but not for general public, of course.

Comment: @David, an app for children which controlled by their parents for example could be also legit in this case...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key

Comment: @kobik A restart would defeat that

Comment: @David only if kids know how to restart :)

Comment: I'm almost sure this is not possible. You see even if you disable the "Home" and "Back" buttons in your app, the user can drag the notification bar down and switch applications then use the "Home" button from there. Also I'm pretty sure you can't disable those buttons systemwide. And how about the "Switch task " button.

Comment: @Dalija I guess you don't have kids!!

Comment: @David only three... I didn't say that you can use that method forever...

Comment: Reconsidering the case, **I strongly hope** that is not possible. It would be a massive bug in the Android system and as one, even if it is possible somehow, a later fix would disable your "solution".

Comment: @David, "A restart would defeat that" I'm pretty sure you could set an app to automatically start on Android (after restart) - given the right permissions. Take a look at this nice app: [Kids Zone Parental Controls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ootpapps.kids.zone.app.lock&hl=en)

Comment: @kobik that would be a pretty useless device

Comment: With all those Google's ways to get a dollar, Delphi users still want to create ransomware... Just amazing!

Comment: I can think of plenty reasons why one would wish to disable these buttons, but I see no reason why Android would make it available.

Comment: @David, well if the device belongs to my child and I do want to restrict him, I think it is legit. in any case I just gave an example where this can be useful. I don't think the OP deserves down-votes. it's a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key) actually.

Answer (score 10):

From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Using_the_Android_Device.27s_Back_Button)

> Using the Android Device's Back Button
>
> To make your application handle when users press the Back button on
>   their Android device, add an event handler to your form for OnKeyUp,
>   and use the following code within your event handler: In Delphi:

```
if Key = vkHardwareBack then
begin
  // Do whatever you want to do here
  Key := 0; // Set Key = 0 if you want to prevent the default action
end;
```