# Disabling the home button on a bluetooth keyboard programatically in an android application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bluetooth

I'm making an Android app using Xamarin and C#. The app will always be running in Kiosk-mode in which the bottom navigation bar of the device will be removed and navigation outside of the app is blocked.

However, when the user connects a bluetooth keyboard they can hit the physical home button and return to the android home screen which should not be accessible.

I'm aware that there are ways to [disable the home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key), but I haven't been able to get any of them to work properly as they're generally hacks since Android doesn't directly allow developers to intercept the home button.

Is there anyway I can remap the home key of bluetooth keyboards connected? Are there any other solutions to this that I maybe overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intercept Android Home Button due to security of device, however if you have rooted device you can experiment with Android **Key Layout Files** https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files.html

But that requires root on device

Comment: Will this let you remap the keys of a specific input device, or all input devices together?

Comment: For specific rooted device.

Comment: Thanks! A down-side of this method is that it requires not only root, but write access to /system. Some rooted devices don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Another method with root is to find the correct /dev/input/eventX device, get exclusive access to it, and then use the /dev/uinput interface to create a new device. Then write all events from the keyboard other than home key to the new interface. I haven't tested this, but in theory it should work.
2. You could perhaps create a dummy launcher that simply exits as soon as it starts. But it would disable the home button altogether, not just on the BT keyboard.