# Create scanner view for android

Tags: android, java.util.scanner

How can create scanner view for android?
I want to development only blood pressure prank scanner.

When i touch on layout automatic scan for 5 second.
How can i manage time session?

Comment: `Timer` ? `Long click` works for 2 3 seconds as well

Comment: when i release button it can stop

Comment: you can use the layout `onTouch` listener and its events `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` to start and dismiss timer

Comment: please give me example or source code...

Comment: great it's working...

Comment: Can u tell me how to disable home button when activity open?
Please tell me...

Comment: You cannot completely disable the home button however you can put flags in your Manifest look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key

Comment: but i use this code my app is creased.