# Android Getting to Blank Homescreen

Tags: android

I am working on a tablet that will not feature all the navigation buttons, just powerup, so I need a way to go from an activity to show the home screen.  What Intent action can i fire that is guaranteed to show clear homescreen?  What intent\action fires when you click on the device button that takes you to homescreen.  Thanks?

Comment: What tablet are you working on that doesn't have the HOME button?

Comment: Thats part of the product design.  Its a dedicated tablet to run just one app.

Answer (score 0):

just call the following code from any activity:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

You may want to add a button of some sort to invoke this function.
Good luck

Comment: so just context.moveTaskToBack(true)  Is that what the button acctually does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and finish() all of your activities. Maybe in Application keep a ivar that is showHome, if true on resume() in each activity just call finish(). This is not really standard android behavior though.

Edit**
If you want to fire their launcher you can checkout this thread:
[Going to home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

Comment: ok.  but in android if you push a certain button you always get back to home screen.  What Intent is this sending out?

Answer (score 0):

Untested Code:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setClassName("myPackage","myPackage.MyClass");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        try {
             startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"myMethod",e);
        }
```