# Android: How should i open home screen from my application?

Tags: android

How should i open home screen from my application ?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher");
startActivity(i);
```

This code is working when i open

```
com.android.browser
```

but isnt working for

```
com.android.launcher
```

What might be the problem ? Package name or some other ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Going to home screen Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
ask the user to open any app

Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```