# How to go to the default home screen of Android programatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen

In my app, I have a button called *EXIT*, when the user clicks that, I want to finish all the activities of my app, which are in the stack, and go to the default home activity or the all apps activity.

I have written the following code in my `onClick()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

But it gives me the following error in logcat:

```
03-12 11:22:18.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.category.HOME }
```

So what do I need to do to achieve this? Do I need some configuration in the manifest or is my approach wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Going to home screen programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Comment: Is it finishing all the activities from the stack task?

Comment: No. This code will take you to the home screen. I just gave you the code to to go to the default home screen. (As I see in your log, it was throwing exception). To finish all your activities of your application, you will have to write logic which should get called before this code.

Comment: will Intent.FLAg_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP do that, as every activity is on the top of the home activity.

Comment: I guess finish() method may be helpful

Comment: As per doc of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP = "For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B."
For that you should start your application from home app only. I also tried above code with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it retains the state and does not clear the back stack. You can simply check this by calling above code, then just long press the home button. Your app is running with old state.

Comment: Chandra is actually correct. If you have a launcher, and you programmatically go to HOME as you have answered, all the activities are finished from the stack task. Try it, you will see that you will not be returned to the Activity you launched the default Home screen from

Comment: Causes ActivityNotFoundException for some users of my app having devices with Android 5.1.1. Details: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] }

Answer (score 3):

use following code to launch home screen:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, HomeClass.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```