# Is there a way to minimize the app to the background with a button inside the app?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, minimize

Is there a way to **minimize the app** to the background with a button inside the app?

Some apps do that when you press the exit option. They don't close but put the app in the background...

I want to do that with my Ionic app or with a cordova way.

Comment: how did you did this?  I have also same requirement so can you please tell me?

Comment: Thanks . I will look here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just created a plugin called "*AppMinimize*" for cordova (*only for Android devices*) that does what you want. I hope it helps you.

---

#### Installation:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize.git
```

---

#### Usage:

```
window.plugins.appMinimize.minimize();
```

---

#### Ionic Example: Minimize app by pressing back button:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.plugins.appMinimize.minimize();
}, 100);
```

---

#### Github:

https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ionic-3, solution from [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize/) works like charm

1. Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

   ```
   $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appminimize 

   $ npm install --save @ionic-native/app-minimize
   ```
2. Add this plugin to your app's module
3. Usage

   ```
   import { Platfrom } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { AppMinimize } from '@ionic-native/app-minimize';    

   constructor(private platform: Platform, private appMinimize: AppMinimize) { }

   ...

   this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
   this.appMinimize.minimize();
   });
   ```

Answer (score -3):

You can do so using [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) logic. Here is the android code you can find [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Let you do the rest to translate it in cordova/ionic ( don't know that framework)