# Overriding default back button behavior in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I just recently learned how to clear the backstack in Android. I have two activities, one for login (LoginActivity) and one to use the application (MainActivity). It consists of a bunch of fragments. This is the code I used to start the MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Everything works fine, when I'm on the MainActivity and I press the `home` button, the application closes. When I open it back up, it opens the MainActivity. But when I press the `back` button, it's closing the application and when I open it back up, the LoginActivity is opening. How do I override the `back` button so it behaves the same as the `home` button.

Comment: you can just put @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
} in side your main activty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000319/3790150

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you want to override the back button behavior to move the app to the background instead of doing the usual back button behavior.

You can do this by overriding `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use activity's method.

from activity,

```
onBackPress()
```

from fragment,

```
getActivity().onBackPress()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start Luncher Application in your MainActivity's onBackPressed(),it seems you press the home button.

According to :[Going to home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```