# Android programming back button

Tags: android

I am calling Activity2 from Activity1 through intent and on pressing back button I want my activity2 not to get destroyed and go back to Activity1 and again from activity1 want to start activity2.
I have tried to override the back button but then by using moveTaskToBack(true)
is taking me back to my phones home screen but i want to come back to previous activity.

Comment: Use fragments for this purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding default back button behavior in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637887/overriding-default-back-button-behavior-in-android)

Comment: I tried to override default back button but then it is taking m e back to home screen but i want to come back to the activity which has called it.

Answer (score 0):

Activities (and Fragments) are designed to destroy when `onBackPressed` is called. Since the user has no intention to proceed interaction with the screen anymore.

I think the best approach of your navigation should be use of Fragments with manually handled navigation. When `Activity` starts initialize both `Fragment`s. When you'll need to open second screen, just replace current fragment with `Fragment2`. When `onBackPressed` is called - replace `Fragment2` with `Fragment1`. In this case both fragments are always available to be shown.

One thing to be aware of - state saving, since the system can destroy your app in the background anyway. In this case, save state manually when `Activity` is being destroyed.