# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change activity type once set

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am getting the below stacktrace in the crashlytics dashboard for my Android project. I could not reproduce the issue. I would like to know more about the below stackstrace and the possible scenario in which this exception could be triggered and reproduced. Is this anything to do with launch mode?

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change activity type once set: { mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2094) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2094) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=home} activityType=standard
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1974)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3619)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4689)
   at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:588)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4647)
   at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5008)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4976)
   at com.myapp.UtilsKt.exitApplication(Utils.kt:207)
   at com.myapp.MyActivity.onBackPressed(MyActivity.java:329)
   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3169)
   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3383)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3452)
   at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:122)
   at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
   at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:140)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:599)
   at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3068)
   at com.heapanalytics.android.eventdef.WindowCallbackTouchTracker$TouchInterceptingWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackTouchTracker.java:210)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:563)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6035)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5890)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5362)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5521)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5578)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5362)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5362)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5554)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5723)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3407)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2854)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2845)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3384)
   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)


Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at android.app.WindowConfiguration.setActivityType(WindowConfiguration.java:366)
at android.app.WindowConfiguration.setTo(WindowConfiguration.java:390)
at android.content.res.Configuration.setTo(Configuration.java:1136)
at com.android.server.wm.ConfigurationContainer.onConfigurationChanged(ConfigurationContainer.java:124)
at com.android.server.wm.ConfigurationContainer.onParentChanged(ConfigurationContainer.java:523)
```

Following is the implementation that I did in my util.kt file

```
fun exitApplication(activity: Activity) {
    val exitIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    activity.startActivity(exitIntent)
}
```

Following is the onBackPressed implementation of my MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    exitApplication(this);
}
```

Any help or guidance on this problem would help me to solve this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005798/illegalstateexception-cant-change-activity-type-once-set

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity launch mode "standard" to any other launch mode.