# How to Go to home screen programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to go to the **home screen**(Minimize App) programmatically in Android when the user clicks on button How can this be done?

I have Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically) approach but its giving Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException Exception for some devices.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: How is this useful for a user? If user wants to go home, he can just press the home button.

Comment: Does the app have to be paused? Otherwise, just call 'finish()' and the app is closed.

Comment: when we press home button it will pause app and minimize app,i want this behaviour

Comment: Just call finish() then

Comment: @m0skit0 its a requirement of client,he dont want that all activity got closed  he just want to minimize,

Comment: finish() will kil activity not minimize

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace.  See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method

```
this.moveTaskToBack(true); //if you are inside activity
```

Elsewhere

```
activity.moveTaskToBack(true); //activity is the reference of your Activity.
```

Read more about this method here [moveToBack)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#moveTaskToBack(boolean))

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: please read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#moveTaskToBack(boolean)

Comment: I have single activity and all the task is done by fragment transaction and replacement of it

Comment: It moves the task which has the activity to the back of the stack. So it works. Try it

Comment: okay ill try and let you know

Comment: Thanks, But its not working , this solution recreating the activity and all fragment loaded again

Comment: no, it won't recreate the activity. it only stops the activity ondestroy() will not be called this way. please put logs and test this method.

Comment: if all the fragments are loading again then you should look in to the code where you initialise fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210428/discussion-between-rajendra-dabhi-and-jayanth).

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button, you can use this to go to home screen of phone

```
private fun goToHomeScreen() {
    val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
    startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    startActivity(startMain)
}
```

But its not a **best practice of programming** because if phone doesn't have more memory then your app will be automatically killed in the background. Your app will be resumed if there's memrory left in the phone.

Comment: Quoting OP: I have Tried this approach but its giving Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException Exception for some devices.

Comment: which phone and os?

Comment: "if phone doesn't have more memory then your app will be automatically killed in the background" isn't why this isn't a best practice...that's just how Android apps work.

Comment: If you want to resume your app then it is not a valid solution that's I am saying ! @Ryan M

Comment: Galaxy tab s4 and its  has 1.5gb free ram and 45gb memory free at that time when it crashed by above exception

Comment: It is a valid solution if you have written your onSaveInstanceState and state restoration correctly.

Comment: I just want to understand this why this error said that security exception "java.lang.SecurityException Exception"