# Entering background mode

Tags: java, android

How to programmatically, e.g. using a button, make the app switch to background mode. Actually, I mean the action that the "home screen button" does, but I want to programmatically do it on my button. Thanks.

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Cause exited from app.

Comment: Try the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883844/how-to-go-to-home-screen-programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below backstack function to move the app to background mode:

moveTaskToBack(true)