# Using Android Studio Hiding an application

Tags: android

I have an Android Studio application that capture
phone screen.
With on press of a button (start capturing), I would like to hide the main screen.
then when I want to finish I press the application icon and show the
main screen again.

Comment: I guess you're looking for `moveTaskToBack`

Answer (score 0):

Press home button
[Going to home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724509/going-to-home-screen-programmatically)

```
           Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
```