# Remove state maintenance of screens Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new developer for Android application so please ignore if there is some technical mistakes in my question.

I have five screen (Home, SR-1, SR-2,SR-3,SR-4 ) in my Android application and I can switch any screen at give time.

When we are pressing device back button it will take we to the previous screen where I was lastly.

But whenever I am pressing Home it will take me to landing screen If in this state I am pressing device back button I will take me to previous view but I want to remove this state maintenance.

(i.e. : When I am coming to Home and I pressed back button It will exit from my application)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each activity: you can add in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="nameofActivity"
android:noHistory="true"></activity>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This will not maintain history but I want to remove history when I press Home and after home app will have to start maintaining history again.

Answer (score 1):

From [android pressing back button should exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354336/android-pressing-back-button-should-exit-the-app) :

Immediately after you start a new activity, using `startActivity`, make sure you call `finish()` so that the current activity is not stacked behind the new one.