# does not close android app by pressing back button

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android pressing back button should exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354336/android-pressing-back-button-should-exit-the-app)

I am trying to close an app using mobile's back button. Currently I am overriding `onKeyPressed` method and calling `moveTaskToBack(true);`. It does hides the app but does not close it. It still remains in the memory. How can I close the app by pressing the back button?

Here is my  code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is correct behaviour.  Why do you want to close your app?  In nearly every situation, you should let Android handle memory management and app closing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its safer to do `this.finish();` instead.

`System.exit(0)` is not recommended, better let `Android` do the management of the app.

Check this link : [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Well, not completely.

An app's lifecycle is made in such a way that being in the background is normal and expected. This allows apps to be quickly restored to the front if/when the user wants, and allows Android to do the memory management. You have special methods like `onPause()` and `onResume()` to help you handle this.

Beyond that, `finish()` will close the current activity and remove it from the stack, while `System.exit(0)` should close the app.

You should read an excellent answer by CommonsWare (Mark Murphy)  to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033914/1069068) question, as it addresses a number of reasons to let Android keep your app in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you push the new activity, call finish() on the previous, otherwise it will remain on the stack, therefore appearing when you hit back and pop the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `finish()` to close down your app.
However if it's due to memory management, I'd rather use android's own memory management. It's actually quite good. It will periodically remove applications which are paused, if it's necessary to free up memory. And unless it's a service, it shouldn't take up too much memory while lying in the stack. There are exceptions however.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hold it to me but I believe onbackpressed is now the recommended method. And yes finish () ; should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `System.exit(0)` to **close** you app at the back button, this is quite useful with java application, same works for Android, but **then it would be advisable to use the below methods.**

`finish()` and `finishActivity()` are 2 alternatives

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit application, write following:

```
finish()
```

because **System.exit(0)** is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658083/1777090).
This will also exit from your application.

Comment: I use System.exit(0); to exit from my application. @DineshVenkata You have any solution for that? and Y you give negative point? its working.

Comment: have a look at the documents its never advised to use System.exit(0) as it is not a part of the lifecycle of an activity

Comment: Because you should always be a good Android citizen.  Android works much better (and faster) when it can manage memory and loading/unloading apps itself.  It is very rare that System.exit() is needed, it is bad practice and just because you can do does not mean you should.

Comment: Infact he down voted my comment @simon

Comment: Sorry, my comment is for Hardik.

Comment: @Simon i edit my answer thanks for giving such a knowledge.

Comment: @Simon I understand what I meant was he was not comfortable with the down vote for his answer.

Comment: @hardikjoshi what happend why did you change your mind?

Comment: @DineshVenkata i not know perfectly about System.exit(0) so that i edit it. Now onwards i never use it and find alternative for it.

Comment: good but you shouldn't have down voted my comment without realizing what you did.

Comment: @DineshVenkata sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

`System.exit(0)` closes the entire app.
`finish()` is another snippet that closes the current activity.