# Exit from Android app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Suppose I have A->B->C->D activities.
I want to exit from C always `onBackPressed()`.

How to exit from application on such situation. I have tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but no success.

My Minimum SDK is `API 8`.

Comment: If you want to exit `C` Activity always then implement `onBackPressed()` inside `C` Activity and impose `finish()` inside that method.

Comment: If you dont have to go to the previous activites why cant you finish activity A and Activity B when you go to activity C?

Comment: @bill gates, the Activites are started from onpost executes of task so  i am not able to kill them.

Comment: @VikalpPatel that will just finishes the C and bring the B forward.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
```

Comment: your solution is working well. but one case : if the i run the app again immediately after the app close it is showing the B.how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AppExit()
{

    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    /*int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();=====> use this if you want to kill your activity. But its not a good one to do.
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);*/

}
```

call this method when you click `back` button

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit only onBackPressed() in C then all you have to do is override the onBackPressed() in activities A, B and D by doing this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

This will ensure that when back key is pressed in A, B and D, application doesn't close. You don't need to override onBackPressed() in activity C as Android calls finish() by default. But if you want to pop up an alert dialog then you can do as follows -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertbox.setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit the application");
            alertbox.setCancelable(false);
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                }
            });

            alertbox.show();
}
```

Finally to take care that previous activities close when you try to finish the activity in C, you should call finish() whenever you start a new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
In Activity A,

```
    startActivity(new Intent("B"),request_code);
```

In onActivityResult() function,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_code) 
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in Activity B,

```
startActivity(new Intent("C"),request_code);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_code) 
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally in Activity C ,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
{ 
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the functionality of back button in your `Activity C` and exit from application, if it was pressed. Try this:-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //Back key pressed
       //To Do - Exit App in your case
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add this code in your Activity which you want to exit

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Exit")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this APP ")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();    
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
```

Are otherwise you may refer to this [**Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354336/android-pressing-back-button-should-exit-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

it already has the post time:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html

```
this.FinishAffinity();
```

Answer (score 0):

finish your current_activity using method `finish();`

and then add below lines in onDestroy of the current_activity for Removing Force close

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```